# How to include Fortran .inc files to C program

Tags: c, fortran, language-interoperability

I have a program written in Fortran, and some variables are defined in `.inc` files. I want to call self-written C function from the Fortran program, and this function must read and write data to the variables. How should I let know C function about this variables? I'm using gcc and gfortran as compilers.

Comment: [ISO_C_BINDING](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/ISO_005fC_005fBINDING.html). See a worked example [here](https://www.scorec.rpi.edu/wiki/Iso_c_binding)

Comment: Often what's found in "INC files" are declarations for common blocks.  Is that your situation?